# Prove that the 4 points can construst a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

As the figure shows, line $AB$ is perpendicular to line $CD$, and they intersect at $E$. Construct four circles with centers $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and radii $AE$, $BE$, $CE$, $DE$ respectively. Let $F,G,H,J$ be the intersections of those circles different than $E$. Prove that $F,G,H,J$ are on the same circle

I've tried to use the trigonometric functions to do it, which is a 'hard way'. But, I am sure that there is a much easier way to solve it. Can someone help me?

Image is for reference

[image: Image Link]

Comment: PS. I fixed the image link. Please use the built-in paste image button to use imgur.com images only.

Comment: "The straight lines AB and CD are perpendicular to E" makes no sense.  Please explain.

Comment: Can we apply conformal mapping using the function $w=1/z$? The four points become vertices of a rectangle in the $w$ plane, from which concyclicity follows.

Comment: Do you know how to tell whether a quadrilateral is cyclic if you know the angle at each vertex? Obviously you do not know the individual angles here, but with sufficient angle-chasing (of well-chosen angles) you can get the information you need.

Comment: "The straight lines AB are perpendicular to CD" Now look at your drawing...

Comment: If you have trouble writing in English, try [this](https://translate.google.com/)

Comment: Hint: 

Approach 1:

Do inversion with center $E$, and those intersections of circles becomes four vertices of a rectangle. Clearly, all those four points are on a circle.

Approach 2:

Notice that $\angle FJE=\angle FJD$ and other equalities, you can get $\angle FJH=\angle FED+\angle HEC$, and $\angle FGH=\angle FEA+\angle HEB$. You can get $\angle FJH+\angle FGH=180^\circ$

Also, I have fixed your writing of this problem statement.

Comment: Just a recommendation with geogebra;  use "hide" option in order to make labels for line segment invisible.  With this your figure looks simpler.

Comment: This is a rewritten version of USAMO 1993/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\angle FJE=\frac{\angle FAE}{2}=\frac{180°-2\angle FEA}{2}=90°-\angle FEA=\angle FED$

In the same way: $\angle HJE=\angle CEH$, $\angle HGE=90°-\angle CEH$, $\angle FGE=90°-\angle FED$.

Then $\angle FJH + \angle FGH = \angle FJE+\angle HJE+\angle HGE+\angle FGE=$ $\angle FED+\angle CEH+90°-\angle CEH+90°-\angle FED=180°$.

Then $FJHG$ is cyclic quadrilateral.